# require('jquery') not defined using elixir / Gulp

Tags: jquery, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I'm using elixir and I can't get to work any JS using JQuery I keep getting this :

```
var jQuery = require('jquery'); //Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Here is my elixir function:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('app.scss');
    mix.copy('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/fonts');
    mix.copy('node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts', 'public/fonts');
    mix.copy(['node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js',
                'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                'node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
                'node_modules/fullcalendar/node_modules/moment/moment.js',
                'node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js',
                'node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/gcal.js',
                'node_modules/dropzone/dist/dropzone.js',
                'node_modules/jquery-datetimepicker/jquery.datetimepicker.js'
            ], 'resources/assets/js/vendors');
    mix.copy('resources/assets/js/vendors/jquery.js', 'public/js');
    // mix.copy('resources/assets/js/vendors/jquery-ui.js', 'public/js');
    // mix.copy('resources/assets/js/vendors/bootstrap.js', 'public/js');
    mix.scripts(['vendors/jquery-ui.js',
                'vendors/bootstrap.js',
                'vendors/contentflow.js',
                'vendors/qTip/jquery.qtip.min.js',
                'vendors/moment.js',
                'vendors/fullcalendar.js',
                'vendors/dropzone.js',
                'vendors/jquery.datetimepicker.js'
            ], 'public/js/vendors.js');
    mix.scripts(['date-time-pickers.js',
                'main.js',
                'search-page.js',
                'social.js',
                'booking-picker.js'
            ], 'public/js/app.js');
});
```

Any idea what happens? 
Tried

```
mix.browsesify
```

but it would return

```
[Laravel Elixir] Browserify Failed!: Cannot find module 'moment'``
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the warning `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` is something your IDE says because it doesn't understand how these scripts work together. (I get this warning a lot when working with javascript in Laravel Elixir).

The real problem is the missing of the `moment` module. It looks like this package is not installed (correctly). You can try to reinstall it (`npm install --save moment`) or remove the `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again.

Take a look at https://momentjs.com/ for more information about this package. Including a small installation guide for other package managers besides npm.

*Disclaimer. I am not sure if this is the solution for you. In my experience, solving npm/Laravel Elixir problems can be a hassle sometimes. I do not have all the information I need to make sure this solves the problem. It would be nice if you could include the contents of the  `package.json` file or maybe paste a error log from npm. Just let me know.*